# Flattened tree view structure with XSLT keeping nodes structure as connections elements

Tags: xml, xslt, tree

I have the following xml (simplified structure)

```
<Workflow>
    <CreateEntity />
    <Activity Type="Custom" />
    <Activity Type="Condition">
        <Activity Type="ConditionBranch">
            <UpdateEntity />
        </Activity>
        <Activity Type="ConditionBranch">
            <Activity Type="Custom" />
        </Activity>
    </Activity>
    <Activity Type="Custom" />
</Workflow>
```

and want to transform it in that way

```
<WorkflowProcess>
    <Activities>
        <!-- static start with known id -->
        <Activity Id="StartId" />

        <!-- activity from CreateEntity node; id - new GUID -->
        <Activity Id="CreateEntityId" />
        <!-- activity from Custom activity node; id - new GUID -->
        <Activity Id="Custom1Id" />
        <!-- so on -->
        <Activity Id="ConditionId" />
        <Activity Id="UpdateEntityId" />
        <Activity Id="Custom2Id" />
        <Activity Id="Custom3Id" />

        <!-- static end with known id -->
        <Activity Id="EndId" />
    </Activities>
    <Connections>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="StartId" To="CreateEntityId"/>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="CreateEntityId" To="Custom1Id"/>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="Custom1Id" To="ConditionId"/>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="ConditionId" To="UpdateEntityId"/>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="ConditionId" To="Custom2Id"/>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="UpdateEntityId" To="Custom3Id"/>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="Custom2Id" To="Custom3Id"/>
        <Connection Id="new-guid" From="Custom3Id" To="EndId"/>
    </Connections>
</WorkflowProcess>
```

I've written the simplest part of it - getting the list of activities and stuck with creating the connections.

The problem is how to build Connections nodes which are referencing my activities by newly created Id's?

My sample XSL is like (simplified)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:myCustomCode="urn:myExtension">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="startActivityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
  <xsl:param name="endActivityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <WorkflowProcess>
        <Activities>
            <!-- start -->
            <Activity Id="{$startActivityId}" />

            <xsl:apply-templates select="Workflow"/>

            <!-- end -->
            <Activity Id="{$endActivityId}" />
        </Activities>
        <Connections>
            <!-- ???-->
            <!-- how to compose these connections? -->
        </Connections>
    </WorkflowProcess>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Workflow">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CreateEntity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateEntity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='Custom']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='Condition']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CreateEntity">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UpdateEntity">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity[@Type='Custom']">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity[@Type='Condition']">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='ConditionBranch']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity[@Type='ConditionBranch']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Workflow"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update 1:**
Here is a chart that describes the first/source xml (and target too)

[image: sample diagram]

**Update 2:**
Trying to formalize connection rules has come to such chart (with added another activity for example)

[image]

**Update 3:**
This is my firs attempt: accumulate connections in global script object. Since variables in XSLT are immutable we cannot modify them, so I use global object to store connections (see script element). So when I find a new activity, I add it connection to global object right here. It allows me recursively build all the activities with connections.

Modified XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:myCustomCode="urn:myExtension"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="myCustomCode" language="C#">
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Text" />
    <![CDATA[    

      public string NewId()
      {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      }

      private StringBuilder _connections = new StringBuilder();

      public void AppendConnection(string from, string to)
      {
        _connections.AppendFormat("<Connection Id='{0}' From='{1}' To='{2}' />", NewId(), from, to);
      }

      public string GetConnections()
      {
        return _connections.ToString();
      }


    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


  <xsl:param name="startActivityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
  <xsl:param name="endActivityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <WorkflowProcess>
      <Activities>
        <!-- start -->
        <Activity Id="{$startActivityId}" name="start" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="Workflow"/>

        <!-- end -->
        <Activity Id="{$endActivityId}" name="end" />
      </Activities>

      <Connections>
        <!-- output connections from script global value -->
        <xsl:value-of select="myCustomCode:GetConnections()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
      </Connections>

    </WorkflowProcess>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Workflow | Activity[@Type='ConditionBranch']" name="Workflow">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CreateEntity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateEntity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='Custom']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='Condition']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CreateEntity">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='CreateEntity' />

    <!-- build connection to parent -->
    <xsl:call-template name="buildConnection">
      <xsl:with-param name="childId" select = "$activityId" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UpdateEntity">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='UpdateEntity' />

    <!-- build connection to parent -->
    <xsl:call-template name="buildConnection">
      <xsl:with-param name="childId" select = "$activityId" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity[@Type='Custom']">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='Custom' />

    <!-- build connection to parent -->
    <xsl:call-template name="buildConnection">
      <xsl:with-param name="childId" select = "$activityId" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity[@Type='Condition']">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='Condition' />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='ConditionBranch']"/>

    <!-- build connection to parent -->
    <xsl:call-template name="buildConnection">
      <xsl:with-param name="childId" select = "$activityId" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- find parent and add connection to global script variable -->
  <xsl:template name="buildConnection">
    <xsl:param name = "childId" />

    <!-- the main trick is to get parent id here and pass to my custom function -->

    <xsl:apply-templates select="myCustomCode:AppendConnection($childId, 'parentId')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how you determine which activity is connected to which to begin with.

Comment: Activities in source XML are ordered from the top down, and so they do not need the id and connections. Target form have to have Id's and connections.

Comment: I suppose that it's possible to restore connections moving backward from child element to his parent: for the first activity parent is start element (which id is known).

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the pattern. Why don't you give the input nodes some arbitrary ids or unique names (which won't be used in the process) and show these on the output - just so we can see who is who.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change input XML format, but believe that I can use XSLT to convert to target form. Maybe I should use two pass XSLT: first - adds Id's to source, and second one do the trick?

Comment: I would like to see some clear rules how to determine the connections. Evidently, some nodes are connected to their preceding sibling and some to an ancestor. -- P.S. I don't think there is much doubt you will have to do this in two (or more) passes.

Comment: I'll try to formalize it. All the nodes connected to its preceding siblings. If it is the first node in ConditionBranch-activity - it's connected to ancestor, else - to preceding sibling. If preceding sibling of a node is Condition-activity, it connected to all its last nodes from ConditionBranch-activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the final solution bacame very complex, the simplified version is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:myCustomCode="urn:myExtension"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="myCustomCode" language="C#">
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <![CDATA[    

      public string NewId()
      {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      }

      private Dictionary<string, string> _ids = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      /* Converts XSL generated ids to GUIDs */
      public string GetId(string xsl_id)
      {
        if (!_ids.ContainsKey(xsl_id))
        {
          _ids.Add(xsl_id, NewId());
        }

        return _ids[xsl_id];
      }          
    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:param name="startActivityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>
  <xsl:param name="endActivityId" select="myCustomCode:NewId()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <WorkflowProcess>
      <Activities>
        <!-- start -->
        <Activity Id="{$startActivityId}" name="start" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="Workflow"/>

        <!-- end -->
        <Activity Id="{$endActivityId}" name="end" />
      </Activities>

      <Connections>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="conections"/>
      </Connections>

    </WorkflowProcess>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Workflow | Activity[@Type='ConditionBranch']" name="Workflow">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CreateEntity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateEntity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='Custom']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='Condition']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CreateEntity">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id())"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='CreateEntity' name="{@name}" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UpdateEntity">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id())"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='UpdateEntity' name="{@name}" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity[@Type='Custom']">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id())"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='Custom' name="{@name}" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Activity[@Type='Condition']">
    <xsl:variable name="activityId" select="myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id())"/>
    <Activity Id="{$activityId}" Type='Condition' name="{@name}" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Activity[@Type='ConditionBranch']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Connections -->
  <xsl:template match="CreateEntity | UpdateEntity | Activity[@Type='Custom'] | Activity[@Type='Condition']" mode="conections">

      <!-- attach the first element to starting activity -->
      <xsl:if test="local-name(parent::node()) = 'Workflow' and position() = 1">
        <Connection From="{$startActivityId}" To="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(.))}"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <!-- a first element in a condition branch attached to the condition  -->
      <xsl:if test="parent::node()/@Type='ConditionBranch' and position() = 1">
        <Connection From="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(ancestor::*[2]))}" To="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(.))}"/>
      </xsl:if>

      <!-- the last element attached to terminator (ending activity) -->
      <xsl:if test="local-name(parent::node()) = 'Workflow' and position() = last()">
        <xsl:choose>
          <!-- if a last element in workflow is condition attach every its last activities to terminator -->
          <xsl:when test="@Type='Condition'">
            <!-- select only last leaf-nodes of the condition -->
            <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/*[last()][not(child::*)]">
              <Connection From="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(.))}" To="{$endActivityId}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <Connection From="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(.))}" To="{$endActivityId}"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:choose>
        <!-- if previous element is Condition, attach to its last activities -->
        <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/@Type='Condition'">
          <xsl:variable name="childId" select="myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(.))" />
          <xsl:for-each select="preceding::*/*[last()][not(child::*)]">
            <Connection From="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(.))}" To="{$childId}"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- attach to preceding sibling -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <Connection From="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[1]))}" To="{myCustomCode:GetId(generate-id(.))}"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:if test="@Type='Condition'">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="conections"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, that `generate-id()` functions always returns same id for specific node during the transform.

The other point to note how to connect condition child activities to following condition sibling element or terminator.

And last one: I use dictionary to translate generated XSL ids to GUIDs in script block.

Many thanks to @michael.hor257k for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following attempt to implement your rules. Before moving any further, I would like to know if this correctly generates the required connections, in any scenario you might have. I suspect it may not, when conditions are nested.

**XML**

```
<Workflow>
    <CreateEntity name="A"/>
    <Activity name="B" Type="Custom" />
    <Activity name="C" Type="Condition">
        <Activity name="C1" Type="ConditionBranch">
            <UpdateEntity name="C1A" />
        </Activity>
        <Activity name="C2" Type="ConditionBranch">
            <Activity name="C2A" Type="Custom" />
            <Activity name="C2B" Type="Custom" />
        </Activity>
    </Activity>
    <Activity name="D" Type="Custom" />
</Workflow>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Workflow">
    <WorkflowProcess>
        <Activities/>
        <Connections>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="conections"/>
        </Connections>
    </WorkflowProcess>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="conections">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::CreateEntity">
            <Connection From="0" To="{@name}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/@Type='Condition'">
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name" />
            <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*[1]/*/*[last()]">
                <Connection From="{@name}" To="{$name}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@Type='ConditionBranch'"/>
        <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">
            <Connection From="{ancestor::*[2]/@name}" To="{@name}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Connection From="{preceding-sibling::*[1]/@name}" To="{@name}"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>        
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="conections"/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WorkflowProcess>
   <Activities/>
   <Connections>
      <Connection From="0" To="A"/>
      <Connection From="A" To="B"/>
      <Connection From="B" To="C"/>
      <Connection From="C" To="C1A"/>
      <Connection From="C" To="C2A"/>
      <Connection From="C2A" To="C2B"/>
      <Connection From="C1A" To="D"/>
      <Connection From="C2B" To="D"/>
   </Connections>
</WorkflowProcess>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Michael. Unfortunately input XML does not have names or any other id on activity nodes, and I have to generate and assign their id's in XSL. Also there are lots of nested conditions, so I use recursion to travers the tree. Please check update 3 in the question.

Comment: "*input XML does not have names*" I am well aware of that, but I need those names for test purposes - otherwise I will not be able to tell if the result is correct or not. Switching from names to ids is trivial, once you have the correct implementation of the rules. --"*Also there are lots of nested conditions,*" I asked you to state the rules.

Comment: Pardon me for being not so clear, condition is a type of activity, and it can be nested to other condition.
Your XSL correctly generates the required connections, until there is no nested conditions.
As for switching to ids - it is not trivial for me, because input XML doesn't have ids neither names.

Comment: Well, you did not supply rules that would cover nested conditions, and I don't have the time to do this for you. -- As for ids, the `generate-id()` function will generate them for you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to `generate-id()` function - it could be very helpful.
Did not know that it returns same id for specific node during the transform.